# Core Data: Relationship without destination entity?

Tags: objective-c, core-data, nsmanagedobject, data-synchronization

Is it possible to create a relationship without specifying a specific custom NSManagedObject as the destination entity?

E.g., I would like to create an NSManagedObject subclass called `SyncInfo` that will contain attributes regarding syncing and sync options with Parse or some other third party cloud-based database. `SyncInfo` would possess a relationship called `managedObject` that I could then point towards any NSManagedObject that I wish to have synced with Parse. The idea is that I could fetch `SyncInfo` objects from Core Data rather than the data objects themselves when determining which objects need to be synced with Parse. The relationship between a `SyncInfo` object and an NSManagedObject would be 1:1 always.

This is my first time attempting to sync data on my iPhone app with a third party server so I apologize if my best attempt at architecturing this is incorrect. To teach myself I followed the Ray Wenderlich tutorial and got that working and am now attempting to build a slightly more robust version for my app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just create a parent entity that has the `SyncInfo` relationship and base all your other entities on that one.

Look at "Entity Inheritance" [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/Articles/cdMOM.html).

Comment: If you are using a `SQLite` backing store, this will results in one large (sparse) table, and might hinder performance.